# I can't find error in basic select statement

Tags: sql

Look at my where clause, one of them is commented out.

If I run this as is, I get a result of 0

but if I change which WHERE clause I use it works.  I don't understand, @Username equals 'Kleg', yet they obviously are not.  Can someone tell me where I am making my mistake

```
declare @UserName as varchar
set @UserName='Kleg'

declare @return as int
 set @return=(SELECT  userId
        FROM    users
        WHERE   UserName='Kleg')
--        WHERE   UserName=@Username)


SELECT  COALESCE(@return,0)
```

I made my query even more basic, this one is really stumping me, can someone else try this and see if they can duplicate my problem, maybe the problem is in the server

```
declare @UserName as varchar
set @UserName='Kleg'

if (@UserName = 'Kleg')
select 1
else select 0
```

this returns 0

Comment: The answer is always something so simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only have @UserName declared as varchar, if you select @UserName you will see it only returns the first character.

Comment: But it in his example, he's not using the variable (that's commented out) he is using the typed value.

Comment: Aha - after edit of the question, it looks like you might be right...!

Comment: In other words, if you declare it as VARCHAR(5), it will work as you desire.

Comment: yup that is it.  I just ran Select @username, and it returned K.  Wow I have been fighting this for an hour.   I will accept in 5 minutes, once it lets me

Comment: the mistake I made was I had tried to declare it as varchar[50] and it gave me a syntax error. when I used just varchar the syntax was allowed.  I had used [] instead of (), which is what I should have done.  Once again thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting for this, noting the change in how I assigned the variable:

```
declare @UserName as varchar
set @UserName='Kleg'

declare @return as int
SELECT @return = userId
 FROM    users
 WHERE   UserName='Kleg')
--        WHERE   UserName=@Username)

SELECT  COALESCE(@return,0)
```

Note it won't work if there is more than one match with that where clause!

Comment: It still equals 0 I am going to add another query I tried that is failing too which makes no sense, give me a moment then check my question again

Comment: @K'Leg Is there actually a row with `UserName = 'Kleg'`? If so, what's the value of the `UserID` column on the same row?

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing, it's not 100% certain, but it looks very much like when you say

```
declare @UserName as varchar
```

SQL sets up the variable as a `varchar(1)`, meaning you where clause is searching for the value "K". Try this:

```
declare @UserName as varchar(50)
```

or, better, the length of the UserName column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to state how many characters are in your varchar. Change your code to the below and it should work:

```
declare @UserName as varchar(50)
set @UserName='Kleg'

if (@UserName = 'Kleg')
select 1
else select 0
```